# RFC 2822, 3.6.2 error in production for emails following "abc@xyz.co.uk​" format using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, swiftmailer, mailgun

I get RFC 2822, 3.6.2 error thrown (only in production) for email addresses which follow this format:  `abc@xyz.co.uk​`

Source code is as follows:

```
Mail::to($emailAddress, $name)->send($email);
```

Other email formats that pass the Laravel validation work just fine.

I can not reproduce this issue locally

I'm using laravel 5.3

Local:
Windows 10 + homestead + mailtrap

Production:
AWS + forge + mailgun

Swiftmailer version is 5.4.8 (retrieved from composer.lock)

I could reproduce it locally, with Firefox V: 54.0 (32-bit). This seems pretty strange I can't reproduce it in production neither locally with Chrome.
Here is the full exception:

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 345: Address in mailbox given [abc@xyz.co.uk​] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

in MailboxHeader.php line 345
at Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->_assertValidAddress('abc@xyz.co.uk​') in MailboxHeader.php line 261
at Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->normalizeMailboxes(array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in MailboxHeader.php line 106
at Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setNameAddresses(array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in MailboxHeader.php line 63
at Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setFieldBodyModel(array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in SimpleHeaderFactory.php line 58
at Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderFactory->createMailboxHeader('To', array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in SimpleHeaderSet.php line 68
at Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderSet->addMailboxHeader('To', array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in SimpleMessage.php line 329
at Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage->setTo(array('abc@xyz.co.uk​' => null)) in SimpleMessage.php line 305
at Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage->addTo('abc@xyz.co.uk​', null) in Message.php line 151
at Message->addAddresses('abc@xyz.co.uk​', null, 'To') in Message.php line 85
at Message->to('abc@xyz.co.uk​', null) in Mailable.php line 226
at Mailable->buildRecipients(object(Message)) in Mailable.php line 113
at Mailable->Illuminate\Mail\{closure}(object(Message))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Message)) in Mailer.php line 413
at Mailer->callMessageBuilder(object(Closure), object(Message)) in Mailer.php line 207
at Mailer->send('email.user_verification_change_email', array('user' => object(User), 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message)), object(Closure)) in Mailable.php line 117
at Mailable->send(object(Mailer)) in Mailer.php line 192
at Mailer->send(object(UserConfirmationChangeEmail)) in MailableMailer.php line 99
at MailableMailer->send(object(UserConfirmationChangeEmail)) in SendConformationEmailChangedEmail.php line 35
at SendConformationEmailChangedEmail->handle(object(UserEmailChanged))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SendConformationEmailChangedEmail), 'handle'), array(object(UserEmailChanged))) in Dispatcher.php line 354
at Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(object(UserEmailChanged))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(UserEmailChanged))) in Dispatcher.php line 221
at Dispatcher->fire('App\Events\Users\UserEmailChanged') in helpers.php line 480
at event(object(UserEmailChanged)) in InstructorControllerAdmin.php line 198
at InstructorControllerAdmin->update(object(Request), object(User))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(InstructorControllerAdmin), 'update'), array(object(Request), 'users_admin' => object(User))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('update', array(object(Request), 'users_admin' => object(User))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(InstructorControllerAdmin), 'update') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 29
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admins') in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectsMissingPages.php line 13
at RedirectsMissingPages->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/help-with-welcome-email-via-mailgun?page=0 ?

Comment: I came across above link upon my investigations, however it's not my case. It works just fine with other valid email format even the same format on Chrome the issue is only happening with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that

- FROM, TO and REPLY-TO fields are valid, working email addresses
- Domain names are valid
- There are no spaces or other strange characters in addresses (Did you check there are no non-ASCII characters which look like ASCII in string?)

Did you check PHP error logs?

Comment: This issue happen after passing Laravel email validation. It have nothing to do with validation and wrong value.

Comment: All values are valid though. and no PHP errof logs. Looks like it's a defect at swiftmailer side with Firefox browser. I submitted an issue for this case at github:https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/960

Comment: Where do you get the email from? Database or text input? Did you check there are no non-ascii characters which look like ASCII in string?

Comment: I got the email from text input. You are right there was a non-ascii char in the email"abc@xyz.co.uk​" I pasted the email to Notepad ++ and look for Regular expression `[^\x00-\x7F]+` "k" was detected as non-ascii char. Looks like chrome already take care of this issue but not firefox (or maybe other browsers). Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer since it answers your question?

Comment: Sure, please update the answer I will mark it as an answer :)